# integral confusion when y is a function of x

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm well aware of the definition of an integral and how to compute integrals in general as well as ODEs, but I am confused on the syntax as per below:

the integral of y' with respect to y is simply $\int ydy = y^2/2 + C$

what is the integral though if y is a function of y(x) of y'(x) with respect to dy and dx.

$\int y'(x)dy = y^2(x)/2 + c$?

$\int y'(x)dx = y(x) + c$? I'm not even sure what it means to integrate y'(x) with respect to dx without knowing what y'(x) is as a function of x, correct?  Can we say anything more about this integral/sum?

Comment: I know that it might involve chain rule

Comment: in this case, y is not necessarily a function of x.

Comment: you are integrating an expression of y with respect to Y, not to x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your second item first:
Note that $y(x)$ is an [antiderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) of $y'(x)$ by definition.  Therefore, (usually by the notation introduced in the same definition) $\displaystyle \int y'(x) \,\mathrm{d} x= y(x) + C$ (since any two particular antiderivatives differ only by a constant, this expression represents the set of all antiderivates of $y'$).

Your first item has some definitional complications.  In the usual first year Calculus course, the variable of integration is always an independent variable.  So, in that setting, you should never see $\int y'(x) \,\mathrm{d}y$ because $y$ is clearly not an independent variable.  A way forward is to use the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) to swap the roles of $x$ and $y$, so that $y$ is a new independent variable and $x(y)$ is a dependent variable.  Then using standard results on [differentiation of inverse functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation), we could replace $y'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 1/ \frac{\mathrm{d}x(y)}{\mathrm{d}y} = 1/x'(y)$.  Then, (under some technical assumptions about $x(y)$,)  your integral is $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{x'(y)}$.  I note that this is not similar to your proposed $y^2(x) + C$.  In fact your proposal is sensible the first time you use it $\int y \,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{y^2}{2} + C$, but replacing the integrand with $y'(x)$ creates the complexities described in this paragraph.

Comment: yes agreed that make sense.  But what I'm seeing in some other higher order calculus equations is $\int y(x)dx$, which is clearly not the antiderivative of the derivative and thus yielding the original equation y(x).  In this case, without knowing anything about y(x), would you just guess what the antiderivative function is given other information you know about the problem?

Comment: @PEBguy : "$\int y(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$" is literally the general form of any single variable indefinite integral.  In the absence of more information about $y$, this already is the compact way to say "the antiderivative of $y(x)$ with respect to $x$."